# Autocomplete for make

Tags: command-line, autocompletion

If I set a custom `make` program, is there any way to provide a list of tab completion options that would get activated when I type `:make`+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>?

With custom commands I can do f.i.:

```
command! -nargs=* -complete=customlist,MakeComplete -bar MakeGitbook call MakeGitbook(<q-args>)
```

Is there any similar mechanism for builtin commands, and in particular for `:make`?  Or should I just define a custom command wrapper that calls the built in one but also adds tab completion?

Comment: Writing a custom command is probably your best bet.

Comment: `-complete=customlist,MakeComplete` alreeady does what you want?  I don't quite understand where you're stuck or what does't work like you want.

Comment: That only works for a custom command, I'm after something for the built in make command

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism in vim to change built-in commands.
This is actually a good thing, because you can be sure that default behavior is not changed by plugins.
Also plugins itself can rely on the default behavior, so such a feature (to change builtin commands) would potentially create a lot of headache.

> Is there any similar mechanism for builtin commands, and in particular for :make?

No. If you check vim docs ([here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_40.html#40.2) and [here](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#user-commands)), you'll find that `:command` only works with custom commands, which should start with capital letter (except Next which is also reserved).

> Or should I just define a custom command wrapper that calls the built in one but also adds tab completion?

Yes, this is the way to go.